# Why isn't go embedding files?

Tags: go

I'm trying to embed a text file within my go application, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

I have a file named `hello.txt` in the same directory as my go program, but when I compile and run the code below it doesn't print anything, when it should print the contents of hello.txt.

```golang
package main

import (
    _ "embed"
    "fmt"
)

// go:embed hello.txt
var hello string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(hello)
}
```

I also tried making `hello` a `[]byte` and even using a filesystem and listing all files, both show that there's nothing embedded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot have a space between the `//` and the `go:embed`, otherwise the compiler just treats it as a comment.

The [embed documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) doesn't make this clear, but it's explained in the [documentation for go compile](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/compile#hdr-Compiler_Directives)

> The compiler accepts directives in the form of comments. To distinguish them from non-directive comments, directives require no space between the comment opening and the name of the directive. However, since they are comments, tools unaware of the directive convention or of a particular directive can skip over a directive like any other comment.